# Ember.js {{#each}} value in html tag?

Tags: html, ember.js, handlebars.js

So I am using Ember.js each helper and I am having trouble putting values where I want them.

Here is what I want my html to look like.

```
<div id="item0">
  item0Value
</div>
```

But I can't figure out how to write this in the handlebars template.

This is what I tried.

```
{{#each item in array}}
  <div id="item{{item.id}}">
    {{item.value}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

This gives me an error.

`Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: An error occured while setting up template bindings. Please check for invalid markup or bindings within HTML comments.`

Is there a way to do what I want here? or is it not possible to put values inside the html tags?

Comment: You probably want to use `{{bind-attr}}`: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/

Comment: I still have the same problem. It wont let me combine some text with the id variable. I tried `{{bind-attr id='item'+item.id}}`. Am I just formatting this incorrectly?

Comment: You may have to compute the new value in your ItemController, I don't think you can do it in the template itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ember/guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/#toc_item-controller):

> It is often useful to specify a controller to decorate individual
>   items in the ArrayController while iterating over them. This can be
>   done by creating an ObjectController:

You can use an item controller to generate the values you need, and then access them in your template:

```
{{#each item in array itemController="song"}}
  <div {{bind-attr="item.cssId"}}>
    {{item.value}}
  </div>
{{/each}}

// controllers/song
App.SongController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   cssId: function() {
     return 'item' + this.get('id');
   }.property('id')
...
```

Note: As best practice it is better to declare your `itemController` in the template, and not directly in your `ArrayController`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where to put the itemController?

Comment: it just needs to live in your app namespace. don't get confused by the name. any `ObjectController` in your app will do

Comment: Okay that edit to your answer helped me a ton. I finally got it working! Thank you so much for your help.